# Which desktop environment removes window borders/frames of full-screen windows by default (or easy)?

Tags: desktop-environments, titlebar, window-decoration, maximized

Another question lists a bunch of [Desktop Environments](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/22757).

Because of limited screen space (1024×600), which of them make it **easy to hide/remove window frames/borders/decorations (including title bar) for full screen windows?**

The last time I did this with `maximus` (configured not to maximize windows by itself), a GNOME2 top panel and the “Namebar Applet” (to see the window title in the panel). All three seem a little bit abandoned, so I look for alternatives...

Comment: Sounds like unity, the default shell of ubuntu.http://unity.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @xangua, and apart from Unity?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some pretty interesting combinations of elementary os + super wingpanel + maximus.

http://www.heath-bar.com/blog/?p=685

Answer (score 1):

For gnome-shell this is still doable. Maximus exists, but when I installed it, it did not seem to function. [Method 2 on this page](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html) describes how to alter a config file to get the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own xsession. am on netbook and using super-wingpanel, compiz and cairo-dock
[youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05lGVlxPUS8)

you can make it easy:

> sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
>
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:heathbar/super-wingpanel
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install super-wingpanel
>
> gksudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/your_name

then in gedit:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name=your name
>
> Comment=
>
> Exec=gnome-session --session=your_name
>
> TryExec=gnome-session
>
> Icon=
>
> Type=Application

save...

next:

> gedit /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/your_name

and in gedit:

> [GNOME Session]
>
> Name=your_name Session
>
> RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
>
> RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;panel_top;
>
> DefaultProvider-windowmanager=compiz
>
> DefaultProvider-panel=cairo-dock
>
> DefaultProvider-panel_top=super-wingpanel
>
> DesktopName=GNOME

&logout...

if you are advanced user, instead compiz, set openbox, gala, mutter, metacity.....
instead cairo-dock or super-wingpanel you can set any other dock or panel

Comment: And which of those removes title bars from windows?

Comment: super-wingpanel have intellihide / intellislim feature, even global meny support

Comment: Does it remove window frames/titles?